# Transaction Input - previous hash size?

Tags: transactions, transaction-input

I am reading the bitcoin developer reference and having a look on the transaction input structure. If you have a look here https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#raw-transaction-format it says that the previous output  has 36 bytes. I am confused, because I read also the 'Mastering Bitcoin Book' and this wiki page (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction) and they state that the size is 32 bytes.

Is this a mistake in the reference or is it something new which did not propagate to the other sites? Would be nice if someone could clear that up for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in the developer guide they are referring to the [outpoint](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/outpoint), not the output. The outpoint is a data structure used to refer a particular output, that consists of:

```
outpoint = txid(32 bytes) + output index (4 bytes)
```

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: It does. I would like to set this as answered but have to wait a couple more minutes.